# Connect to a different database after logging in?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I connect to a different database based on a user's log in credentials?

**db_helper.php**

```
<?php

function setDb($company_name, $branch_name) {

    return array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => $company_name.'_'.$branch_name,
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );

}
?>
```

**Select_db.php (/libraries) --> included in autoload.php**

```
<?php

class Select_db {

    public function thisdb($db_settings) {

        return $this->load->database($db_settings, TRUE);
    }
}

?>
```

**model.php** (I seem to be getting an error here, but I can't print it out)

```
      if ($result_num == 1) {

            $first_row = $query->row();
            $stored_password = $first_row->password;


           if (crypt($password, $stored_password) == $stored_password) {
                //Successful login
                $sql = "SELECT
                            company.name As company_name,
                            branch.name As branch_name,
                            branch.id As branch_id
                        FROM 
                            account
                        INNER JOIN
                            branch
                        ON
                            account.branch_id = branch.id
                        INNER JOIN
                            company
                        ON 
                            branch.company_id = company.id
                        WHERE
                            account.username = ?
                ";
                $query = $this->db->query($sql, $username);

                $data = array();
                $data['company_name'] = $query->row()->company_name;
                $data['branch_id'] = $query->row()->branch_id;
                $branch_name = $query->row()->branch_name;

                $this->load->helper('db_helper');
                $db_settings = setDb($data['company_name'], $branch_name);
                $dbname = $data['company_name'].'_'.$branch_name;
                //$dsn = 'dbdriver://root:sprinthr123@localhost/'.$dbname;
                //$this->branch_db = $this->load->database($dsn);



                //I'm guessing the error is somewhere around here 
                //because when I comment it out I don't get the 500 error 
                //code anymore and I'm able to log in to the homepage
                $db = $this->Select_db->thisdb($db_settings); 
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {

            return 0;
        }
```

This model is called when logging in through an AJAX request. What happens is I get a `500` error code in the console so there must be some error, but I can't figure out where?

It has to be dynamic so I can't just simply populate the database.php file in config.

Comment: Please see this https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: it has to be dynamic though? cause there are multiple databases to access. Which one will be accessed dpends on the username that has successfully logged in (already got that covered). Main problem is making the connection. @Naincy

Comment: you write the connection script and make the connection. after successful login of a user close all other db connection (php Function) and enable only what you want. Hope it will help

Comment: @MKGarwa that's a little vague, sorry. So what's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Add this Line in database.php in config directory

```
/********* For Other Database***********************/
    $db['Other']['hostname'] = '192.168.1.191';
    $db['Other']['username'] = 'user589';
    $db['Other']['password'] = 'pass12345';
    $db['Other']['database'] = 'other_db';
    $db['Other']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['Other']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['Other']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['Other']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['Other']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['Other']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['Other']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['Other']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['Other']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['Other']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['Other']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

use 'other' database config in model

```
public function get_a_queue() {
    $otherdb = $this->load->database('Other', TRUE); //loaad second databse
    $qr = $otherdb ->query("SELECT * from users");
    return $qr->result();
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: But I can't foretell yet which database will need to be accessed as it depends on the user's username?